# Heroku: No Rake File Found

Tags: ruby, heroku

I am giving Heroku a spin for the first time, but am having quite a bit of difficulty even getting my app to open without crashing. When searching for the answer to this problem, the nice people on stack overflow suggest that I run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

However, when I do this I consistently get this error back

```
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
```

When I run the trace with it I get back this

```
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:598:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/app/bin/rake:41:in `<main>'
```

I have been searching for the answer for hours but I cannot seem to find one that solves this problem. It is possible I just do not know where to look. Any sort of leads would be exponentially helpful. Thank you!

EDIT

Steps already taken:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "init"
heroku create
git push heroku master
```

and this is where I tried to run

```
heroku open
```

received an error, and to remedy this tried

```
heroku run rake bd:migrate
```

Comment: Have you pushed your code to Heroku already?

Comment: The code has been pushed to Heroku already. I will append my initial question with steps already taken.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can run it locally. cd your project and type:

`bundle exec gem list rake`

if you can not see it here try adding it to your Gemfile by typeing:

`echo "gem 'rake'" >> Gemfile`

then `bundle && git push heroku master`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I tried these steps and received the very same error